# В чем отличе модуля от библиотеки(dll) ?

Tags: c#, dll

Насколько я понял dll способна содержать только процедуры и функции, но ни как не переменные и константы. Я так понимаю что модуль и dll это совсем разные вещи...или нет ?
Если нет, тогда в чем отличие между ними и приведите пример использования модуля.
Просто в хочется кучу констант и переменных вынести в отдельный файл, а все вычисления переложить на библиотеку.
Поиск внятного ответа не дал.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам нужно уяснить себе разницу между сборкой и модулем.

Сборка - это абстрактное понятие. Это набор типов .NET, которые можно к чему-нибудь подключить. Сборка имеет определённое имя, по которому её можно найти. Ещё сборка может иметь версию и цифровую подпись для более строгого поиска нужной версии сборки. Как правило, сборка представляет собой одну .dll.

Но у нас есть программы, часть которых написана на C#, а часть на Delphi. Для того чтобы подключить библиотеки на Deplhi  к .NET-программам, требуется написать на Delphi dll с экспортируемыми функциями, а на C# написать сборку, в которую эти функции были бы импортированы. Такая сборка уже состоит из нескольких dll, каждая из которых называется модулем. Один из этих модулей, который написан на C#, содержит манифест сборки (который содержит имя сборки, описание типов, версию, цифровую подпись и т.д.), остальные - это просто dll, написанные на Deplhi.

В принципе, если сборка состоит только из одной dll, это тоже модуль. Просто это одномодульная сборка. Грубо говоря, модуль - это файл. Сборка - это набор файлов, который подключается как единое целое.

Comment: Спасибо за разьяснение. Хотел бы спросить еще совета:
1) у меня есть куча констант которые хотелось бы вынести в отдельный файл и подключать по мере необходимости. как можно это осуществить ?
2) у меня к примеру есть TextBox в котором находится какое либо числовое значение. есть dll в которой есть функция которая должна осуществить подсчет но для подсчета нужна инициализация переменной=TextBox.Text; получается что за отсутсвием переменной нельзя вызвать функцию ? или я неправильно понял... и значения можно передать через аргументы ?

Comment: @Sier: можно вынести константы в отдельный класс:

    static class GlobalParameters
    {
        public const int numberOfElephants = 2;
        public const double totalLengthOfSnakesInMeters = 90.0;
    }

и использовать: 

    for (int elephantNo = 0;
         elephantNo < GlobalParameters.numberOfElephants;
         elephantNo++)
    {
        //...

Выносить в отдельную сборку вовсе не обязательно.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. с 1 разобрался. Можете подкинуть совет на счет 2 ?

Comment: @Sier: вообще-то, вычисления не должны ничего знать о Textbox'ах. Разделяйте ваш интерфейс и ваши вычисления! Пусть код для вычислений получает входные значения как параметры и даже понятия не имеет, есть ли вообще в программе UI.